# Instance of Read class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I was just starting having fun with haskell when I got stuck.

I'm trying to make my new data type (let's call it `MyType`) instance of the `Read` class. `Mytype` is a type constructor, so it takes another type as parameter. I wanted to write this kind of code

```
    instance (Read a) => Read (MyType a) where
        readsPrec _ r = [foo (read r :: a ), r]
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Could not deduce (Read a2) arising from a use of `read' from the context (Read a).
```

I thought that since a is `Readable` I could just infer it, but apparently I'm wrong. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
I have changed the previous code to

```
readsPrec _ r = [foo (read r :: a ), ""]
```

so if I type: `read "myString" :: MyType a` it works perfectly fine. 
Now I was hoping that if I would use `read "myString"` within a context, I shouldn't have to specify the type to read. But the problem is that with

```
bar (read myString) a
```

where `bar:: MyType a -> a -> MyType a`, I got 
     *Ambiguos variable type*.

Is it possible to do something like that without getting that kind of error?

I hope  it's clearer now, I'm trying to simplify the code but I hope I didn't omit anything crucial.

Comment: Please give the type of foo here, just for completeness.

Comment: foo, it's actually a parser, it's a bit more complicated in my code I was trying to simplify here. Now it actually compile even without the ScopedTypeVariables, but as you said in the other post I probably misunderstood the way readPresc works because now I got 
Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
When I try to read a string as MyType.

Comment: ok so in my case to be correct should be [foo (read r :: a ), ""], hope will be helpful to some other newbies :)

Comment: Sorry, but I find your edit confusing. Can you rephrase that as a question?

Comment: I rephrase it, I hope now it's clearer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code actually typechecks if written as

```
instance (Read a) => Read (MyType a) where
        readsPrec _ r = [(foo (read r),r)]
```

if `foo` has type `a -> MyType a`. The compiler can figure out from the expected type signature of `readsPrec` that the call to `foo` ought to return a `MyType a`, and hence (by the type of `foo`), the expression `read r` ought to have type `a`.

But why does it fail when you annotate that with `:: a`? Because type variables are local to the type signature they appear in. So the `a` there is totally unrelated to the `a` in the instance heade and with `read r :: a` you are actually saying: The expression `read r` can have any arbitrary type. But an arbitrary type has no `Read` instance, hence the error message. In the message, the compiler renamed the inner `a` to `a2` to avoid a name clash.

Your code can work as expected, though, if you add `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the module header. Now, the `a` in `read r :: a` refers to the type of `a` in the instance header and all goes well.

<sup>Note that you are not using readsPrec correctly, but I guess that is not part of the question.</sup>

Comment: I added the ScopedTypeVariables and it actually compile, but when I try to read I got Exception: Prelude.read: no parse.
Could you explain what do you mean about the fact that I'm not using readsPrec correctly? I thought I just needed to return a list with 1 tuple with MyType and the parsed String but apparently I was wrong again.

Comment: You should not return the parsed String but rather what of the String is not parsed yet. Also, the list should contain all possible parses of the String (if there are several) and the empty list if there are none (and not an exception).

In general, if you implement `readsPrec`, chances are hight that you should also use `readsPrec` for `a`.